# Is the "Profile:Edit" module still available?

Tags: profile-edit

This module is exactly what I need. But it's not possible to download/buy it from the devot-ee (https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/profileedit) website.

Does anybody know if it is still available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not - Mighty Big Robot is not developing, selling, or supporting any of their add-ons anymore.

Maybe have a look at [Zoo Visitor](http://ee-zoo.com/add-ons/visitor/).